# Retrieve reviews with the Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: web-scraping, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am interested in scraping review data from Amazon for academic purposes. However, Amazon only provides reviews up to 10 pages for each product, regardless of the total number of reviews available. Thus, I looked up if they provide some API to access their data and in the Product Advertising API documentation it states that it provides access to the customer reviews, but there are no further information on it.

> You get access to a lot of the data used by Amazon including the items for sale, customer reviews, seller reviews, as well as most of the functionality you see on Amazon.com, such as finding items, displaying customer reviews, and product promotions.

Does someone has access to the Product Advertising API and can tell me if you are able to see all reviews for all products on Amazon (not just only the first 10 pages of reviews) and if you can (and if it is allowed) to retrieve those review data (for example through scraping with Python)?

Further, is it possible for me as a non-seller to even get access to the Product Advertising API?

Thank you very much in advance!